# rest assured json array has a size but empty objects

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, web-api-testing, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have a Rest API with GET Method where the response looks like the below:

[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
This response has a changeable size based on query string, so I can't verify it using size method.

Using rest assured, how can validate that the JSON response has empty objects but the JSON array has a size not zero?

In another words: validate JSON has no key-value pair and with array size greater than zero.

I have tried:

```
    body("", Matchers.emptyArray());
    body("", Matchers.nullValue());
    body("isEmpty()", Matchers.is(true))
```

Any suggestions Please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonPath (com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath).

```
String res = "[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]";
List<Object> list = JsonPath.read(res, "$[*]");
System.out.println(list.size());
//25
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```